# How to get xpath using object id?

Tags: object, selenium, xpath

I have HTML code for a input box with following expression:

```
<div id="divId">
    <object id="myId" align="middle" type="application/myId"> 
     <param value="myValue">
    </object>
</div>
```

If i use div id for Xpath, then it points to div bar, but i need xpath for 'Object' only. 
How to get xpath for the above expression.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" Xpath? There is no definitive XPath for an object. All objects have many xpaths.

Comment: @RobbieWareham well, this is slighly incorrect. What you probably mean by _object_ is an element. XML has no objects.

Comment: @dirkk .. this is HTML code, and the object field is for signature canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further detail I can only suggest this XPath :

```
//Object[@id='myId']
```

Comment: I tried with the same but getting error in Selenium IDE as '[error] locator not found: //div[@id='signature']/object, error = TypeError: e.scrollIntoView is not a function'

Comment: post relevant portion of your HTML (edit the question to include it, don't post it in comment). Are you sure `<object>` is direct child of the `<div>`?

Comment: Please check my updated code in question and yes, `<object>` is direct child of `<div>`.

Comment: given HTML markup you posted, this XPath worked for me in XPath tester : `//div[@id='divId']/object`. If this doesn't work for you I believe the problem is somewhere else, not the XPath.